# How do I transfer rich text attachments from one document to another

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, attachment, richtext

I have 2 documents which are supposed work in such a way to be able to transfer files between them. However, it doesn't work. The exception I get is `Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.save() Notes error: One or more of the source document's attachment are missing. Run Fixup to delete the document in the source database.` This happens after I try to call `save()` function on the document to which I've just transfered files from the first.

The functions are below:

```
function transferFiles(docToGetFrom, docToTransferTo, fileFieldFromFirstName, fileFieldFromSecondName) 
{
    var rit1:NotesRichTextItem = getFirstNotesRichTextItem(docToGetFrom, fileFieldFromFirstName);
    docToTransferTo.copyItem(rit1, fileFieldFromSecondName);
    deleteAllFilesFromDocument(docToGetFrom, fileFieldFromFirstName);

    docToTransferTo.save();
}

function getFirstNotesRichTextItem(documentToGetFrom, fileFieldName) 
{
    if (documentToGetFrom == null)
    {
        return(null);
    }
    if (!documentToGetFrom.hasItem(fileFieldName))
    {
        return(null);
    }
    var rit1:NotesRichTextItem = documentToGetFrom.getFirstItem(fileFieldName);

    return rit1;
}

function deleteAllFilesFromDocument(documentToDeleteFrom, fileFieldName) 
{
    var arr = getAllEmbeddedObjects(documentToDeleteFrom, fileFieldName);

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        arr[i].remove();
    }

    documentToDeleteFrom.save();

}

function getAllEmbeddedObjects(documentToGetFrom, fileFieldName) 
{

    var rit1:NotesRichTextItem = getFirstNotesRichTextItem(documentToGetFrom, fileFieldName);
    if (rit1 == null)
    {
        return(null);
    }
    try
    {
    var arr=rit1.getEmbeddedObjects();
    return arr;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        return(null);
    } 

}
```

According to plain logic, I need to do the following in order to make it work:

1. Get attachments from the document A
2. Copy them to the document B
3. Remove attachments from the document A
4. Call `save()` on A
5. Call `save()` on B

I did exactly the same, but nevertheless get this nasty exception. Also, I've tried to solve the problem by setting ***[OLEDisableFX](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21095532)*** to 1, but with no luck. I assume that something must be wrong with the method `copyItem()` (I guess it can only work properly with simple datatypes). What's the problem? Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: what if you first save B, then deal with A?

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably need to detach the attachment from the source document and attach it to the target document. See the NotesEmbeddedObject class for examples.

Comment: With the Domino MIME classes this can be done without detaching the attachments.

Answer (score 2):

Use the CopyItemToDocument method of the NotesItem class.  The following is some code I used in a LotusScript agent but the CopyItemToDocument method is also available in Java and SSJS.

```
    If doc.Hasitem("RTF1") Then
        Set item = Nothing
        Set item = doc.getFirstItem("RTF1")
        Call item.Copyitemtodocument(targetdoc, "targetRTF")
        Call item.Remove()
    End If
```

Comment: But, as the HCL help states:
"When you call this method using a RichTextItem object, file attachments, embedded objects, and object links that are contained within the rich-text item are not copied to the destination document."
https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_COPYITEMTODOCUMENT_METHOD_JAVA.html
So, this approach does NOT help the OP with his task, as he wants/needs to transfer attachments between documents.